# How calculate dimensions of a square in a right-angled triangle?

Tags: geometry, trigonometry

I have a problem, I need to calculate the dimensions of a square in a right-angled triangle:
[image]

Comment: Are you told it's a square?  You have know way of solving it or knowing it is a square as there are infinitely many rectangles it can be.  But if you are told it is a square you can solve it.

Comment: Yes, I'm told it's a square @fleablood

Comment: @Arthur Guiot We say **right-angled triangle**.

Comment: Sorry @NgChungTak but I'm French and I don't speak very well English

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By similar triangles,

\begin{align*}
  \frac{a}{b} &= \frac{x}{b-x} \\
  bx &= ab-ax \\
  x &= \frac{ab}{a+b}
\end{align*}

[image]

Comment: Thank You! That's all I need to finish my problem